# What is the order of an element in $ℤ/2mℤ×ℤ/2ℤ$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I know that the order of every $T∈ℤ/nℤ$ divides the size of the group $n$.

My **question** is: What is the order of an element in $ℤ/2mℤ×ℤ/2ℤ$?

Comment: It is not true that every element $T \in {\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z}$ has order $n$, and it is not true that $nT=T$.

Comment: @ Derek Holt : I edit again the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $(a_1,a_2,...a_n)\in\prod_{i=1}^n G_i$ and $|a_i|=r_i<\infty$ then $$|(a_1,a_2,...a_n)|=lcm(r_1,...r_n)$$

Comment: @ Babak S.: you means lcm or lcd.

Comment: @Chaos: I was thinking of TV so I wrote lcd. :D

Comment: I've not often seen the notation $|g|$ for the order of _an element of_ a group. How would you denote the order of $a\in\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$?

Comment: I knew it from Fraleigh. You think I should write it as $\text{order}(g)=...$ instead prof.?